# How to make Windows Bootable-Installable from existing Installed Windows

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, bootable-media

Does anyone have idea about making Windows 8.1 Bootable-Installable from existing Installed Windows.

I need this because many of the times, I need to reinstall the windows as my system is faulty and get crashes. So I can make a installable-bootable USB Pen Drive from the existing installed windows (with all software and drivers etc), then it would be very much helpful for me. Then I will not have to install the drivers and other my required software, after each time I install the Windows.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**System Image Backup**

If you don't want to use a 3rd party imaging tool you can use Windows' own built-in **System Image Backup**. It's hidden from Start Search, so to access it go to **File History**. It's at the bottom left corner of the window:

[image]

To create a system image you'll need an **NTFS formatted storage device**. Most people use an external HDD to store the backup image onto but you could use DVDs of course:

[image]

When recovering from the system image you'll need either a **Win8.x bootable USB stick** or a  System Repair Disc** which you'll be asked to create when making the image. Go to *Troubleshoot>Advanced Options>System Image Recovery* and just choose the system image you want to recover!

[image]

Sources [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/restore-windows-8-with-system-image-recovery/) and [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9064-system-image-recovery-restore-image-computer-windows-8-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is a imaging or cloning software. There are many having their own pros and cons. They are initially used to make rescue disks. Same you can use to make iso image for your need. Some of them are Macrium Reflect, Magic Iso , Ultra Iso , Ghost Drive etc.